Change work in Germany after 1 year under blue card rules
I have obtained a Blue Card under [18g abs. 1 satz 1 aufenthg]. Along with it, I received a green paper with the following conditions: "Nebenbestimmungen: SELBSTÄNDIGE TÄTIGKEIT ERLAUBT BESCHÄETIGUNG UND AG-WECHSEL. GEMAB § 18G ABS. I S. 1 AUFENTHG ERLAUBT NACH 1JAHR. VERSICHERUNGSPFL. BESCHAFTIG IST BESCHAFTIG, JEDER ART ERLAUBT".
Does this mean that after one year, I can take up any job, even if it does not meet the Blue Card criteria?

After one year under the Blue Card EU, any gainful employment is permitted. However, the salary threshold for the EU Blue Card must still be met for the Blue Card settlement permit.
